# Nginx will only use error pages with certain filenames

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ruby-on-rails

Using Nginx I am able to get the default error pages to work for 404 and others, but only if I name the file exactly after the error code, i.e. 404 -> `404.html`... `40x.html` doesn't seem to work.

I want to be able to diplay the same error page for a lot of different errors, and I've seen something like this done:

```
error_page 400 401 402 403 404 405 406 407 408 409 410 411 412 413 414 415 416 417 418 421 422 423 424 426 428 429 431 451 500 501 502 503 504 505 506 507 508 510 511 /error.html;
```

https://blog.adriaan.io/one-nginx-error-page-to-rule-them-all.html

but I can't seem to get it to work. Any ideas? Renaming the file (and in the config) breaks it.

Comment: You state that `/40x.html` doesn't work. What do you see in the error log? What `location` block serves the file `40x.html` and where is the file located in your file system?

Comment: Silly question, are you aware that linux filesystems are case sensitive? You're not trying to open 404.Html or similar? Also, you'll have to give some logs to be able to help you further I think

Comment: Apologies for the terribly late reply, I've been on leave. Nothing in the logs and no filename mistakes. The thing is it doesn't matter what I configure in `sites-available`, it could be 40x.html or nothing at all, so long as their is a file named `404.html` in the public folder, it will get served (didn't even need an nginx restart although I always give it one).